# FTP upload with libcurl: getting CURLINFO_DATA_IN, timing out

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am uploading to an FTP server using libcurl.  In general things are working properly but I always get a timeout error with a specific server (timeout is set to one minute).  The upload of the file itself does happen properly.

I used curl_easy_setopt with CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION to setup a debug function to see what's going on.  Once upload starts, I see that curl_infotype is set to CURLINFO_DATA_OUT for many calls, but I also see several calls where curl_infotype is set to CURLINFO_DATA_IN.  Then, once upload is done but the server still connected, I keep getting curl_infotype set to CURLINFO_DATA_IN until the timeout is reached.

Some questions:
- why am I getting this CURLINFO_DATA_IN?
- how am I suppose to respond to it?

[Edit - I forgot to mention that FileZilla can upload to that server properly]

Answer (score 0):

The debug callback gives you the actual data that is being sent and received, did you look at that data yet to see what it is?  The FTP server does send a reply back to the client after a transfer completes, so that may account for the `CURLINFO_DATA_IN` notifications you are seeing.  It is possible that maybe the server is sending back a reply that libcurl does not recognize correctly so it keeps waiting for more data that will never arrive.  It is hard to say for sure without seeing what the actual communication back and forth really looks like.